# Python - Error opening pickle file created with job lib

Tags: python, compression, pickle, joblib

I've inherited a dataset stored in a pickle file, which was to the best of my knowledge, created in python 3.

I am trying to open the pickle file in python using the following code:

```
f = open('file.pkl', 'rb')
cl = pickle.loads(f)
```

When I do so, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedReader'
```

A similar error is thrown when I try to read it in with only an `'r'` argument.

I can see that the pickel file has been created with joblib, which I have never used before. I can't find any documentation saying if joblib pickel files need to be opened a different way.

Here is the code to create the pickle file:

```
joblib.dump(list_of_dataframes, 'file.pkl', compress=3)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

This also won't open when I try to load directly from `joblib`:

```
with open(pickle_file) as f:
    data = joblib.load(f)
```

Which throws the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, and it wasn't what I expected! (Thank you @JohnGordon for earlier help.) My file was corrupted because it was too large to do a direct pull from GitHub. To fix this, I used [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com) and did a `git lfs pull` instead of a `git pull`. Now unpickling works without errors.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong load function.

You're calling `pickle.loads()`, but you should be using `pickle.load()` instead.

`.loads()` works with strings, and `.load()` works with file objects.

Comment: Thanks! When I try this, I get the following error message: `UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x1f'`

Comment: Can you post the code of `joblib.dump()`?  We need to see how the file was actually created.

Comment: Here it is: `joblib.dump(list_of_dataframes, 'file.pkl', compress=3)`

Comment: That doesn't actually create the file -- `joblib()` is some sort of wrapper function.  We need to see the actual calls to `pickle.dump()`.

Comment: Or, to try a different way, perhaps there is a `joblib.load()` function?

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure if the person who created the code had some kind of backend wrapper that I can't see. In the python file I was given it goes straight from `import joblib` to the `joblib.dump()` argument without importing `pickle`. When I try `joblib.load()` I get this error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte`